# Firebase Recyclerview not displaying in fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am currently trying to implement a firebase listing adapter to load all my UI elements from a Firebase database but when I get to that fragment nothing is shown and there is no error. My other fragments work fine too. I think that the Recyclerview is possibly loading but is covered by a layout. I think I am missing the getItemCount() function in the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter but I am not sure how I could implement it.

```
package com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.adapter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.Listing;
import com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.R;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

// Firebase version of the recycler adapter which fetches listings from a JSON file

public class FirebaseListingAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Listing, FirebaseListingAdapter.listingViewholder> {

    public FirebaseListingAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Listing> options) {
        super(options);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull listingViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Listing model) {
        View view = holder.itemView;

        // Sets Textviews to proper Listing values
        holder.itemTitle.setText(model.getListing_title());
        holder.itemDesc.setText(model.getListing_description());
        holder.itemDate.setText(model.getListing_date());
        holder.itemTime.setText(model.getListing_time());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public listingViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new FirebaseListingAdapter.listingViewholder(view);
    }



    class listingViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView itemTitle, itemDesc, itemDate, itemTime;
        public listingViewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listing_title);
            itemDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listing_desc);
            itemDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listing_date);
            itemTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listing_time);
        }
    }
}
```

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.Listing;
import com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.R;
import com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.adapter.FirebaseListingAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import butterknife.BindView;

/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
* Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
* create an instance of this fragment.
*/
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

   private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
   private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
   private NavigationView navigationView;
   private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
   @BindView(R.id.mRecyclerView)
   RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
   DatabaseReference mbase;
   FirebaseListingAdapter mListingAdapter;

   public HomeFragment() {
   }

   /**
    * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
    * this fragment using the provided parameters.
    *
    * @param param1 Parameter 1.
    * @param param2 Parameter 2.
    * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
    */
   // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
   public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
       HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();

       return fragment;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       mListingAdapter.startListening();
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       mListingAdapter.stopListening();
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       return rootView;
   }

   @Override
   public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
       layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext());
       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       mbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("listings");
       mbase.keepSynced(true);
       FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Listing> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Listing>().setQuery(mbase, Listing.class).build();
       mListingAdapter = new FirebaseListingAdapter(options);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mListingAdapter);

       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       mListingAdapter.startListening();

   }
}
```

```
package com.example.yardscapelistingprototype;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.fragments.CreateFragment;
import com.example.yardscapelistingprototype.fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class HostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle("Yardscape");
        }

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Setup toggle to display hamburger icon with nice animation
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView nvDrawer) {
        nvDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                selectDrawerItem(item);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;

        // Creates a new fragment based on which
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.create:
                fragmentClass = CreateFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        item.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(item.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occured
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: try
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

Comment: Just tried that, no luck

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.